# Uniqueness and existence of a continuous extension

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, continuity

Suppose that $A\subset X$ and suppose that $f\colon A\to Y$ is a continuous function. I know that there is at most one continuous extension $g\colon\bar{A}\to Y$, if $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Unfortunately, I haven't found an existence theorem. So my question is:

**Under what conditions does a continuous extension exist**?

If you come up with a theorem, please tell me where i can see the proof (if you know more uniqueness theorems, you are welcome to tell me).

Comment: The first one that comes to mind, which is quite elementary, is that if $X$ is a metric space, $f$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ and $Y$ is a complete metric space, then $f$ may be extended to $\overline A$.

Comment: @Gae.S. Thank you :)

Comment: Titze extension theorem may be useful with $Y=\mathbb{R}$? It says that in a normal topological space $X$, each bounded, continuous function $f:F\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined on a closed subeset $F\subseteq X$  has an extension to a bounded, continuous function defined on all $X$. You can find a proof in "Analysis now" of Gert K.Pedersen or in any decent book on general topology (maybe i've seen a proof in "Basic Topology" of Armstrong).

Comment: See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78637/extending-continuous-function-d-to-i-where-d-is-a-dense-subspace-of-a-separ) MO thread.